# MySQL,PhP, and Flash As3 Data is not loading properly?

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash, loading

For some reason the PHP variables are loading very improperly. So this is what happens:

In my PHP code I have:

```
<?php
include_once "connect.php";

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($_POST['systemCall'] == "checkLogin") {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";

    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    $login_counter = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($login_counter > 0) {
        while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

            $testing = $data["testing"];
            $userbio = $data["user_bio"];

            print "thetesting=$testing";
            print "theuserbio=$userbio";
        }
    } else {
        print "theuserbio=The login details dont match our records.";
    }
}
?>
```

Then in my AS3 Code I have:

```
import flash.text.*;


result_text.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

result_text.text = "" + event.target.data.theuserbio;
result_text2.text = "" + event.target.data.thetesting
```

What happens is that whenever I login using the correct credentials the `result_text.text` will say `undefined`.

But the `result_text2.text` will say: `HELLOtheuserbio=this is the user bio`.

Basically whats happening is that the `result_text2` is saying both `theuserbio` and `thetesting`. While `result_text` is saying `undefined`.

How do I make it so that `result_text` says the data inside `theuserbio`, and `result_text2` says the data inside `thetesting`?

Comment: Please post your PHP code inline here. And indent it.

Comment: Your PHP looks to SQL injection vulnerable, FYI.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, but I don't really mind for now I'm trying to get this to work.

Comment: I added the PhP code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add ampersand between prints

```
print "thetesting=$testing";
print "&";
print "theuserbio=$userbio";
```

And check that you have this line:

```
urlloader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
```